# Problems when importing factor variables from Stata using readstata13 package

Tags: r, readstata13

I have a very odd problem. I'm importing some factor variables from Stata into R using `readstata13` package. The imported labels/levels look ok, but they change when removing factor class. Here is the Stata description of the variable ([here](https://mega.nz/file/hUgl2QpR#9Rsel8Rm6j6jj87kogDKIPHg-9R2bsrWSbJ28dR3Q_c) is the data for reproducibility):

[image: This is an image]

Notice some labels are missing (UPDATE: actually, they are not missing. Rather, they are filled with a space, an odd way the coder used to highlight missing label). Notice also variable value 13 has 7 observations.

So I import the data in R and check levels and frequency. All fine:

[image: Image here]

Then I remove the levels using `as.integer()` (or `as.numeric()`), but things mess up. In particular values 11, 12 and 13. Notice now 11 has 7 observations, rather than 13:

[image: Image here]

The problem remains, regarding of `read.dta13` options related to factors. I tried the second suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38705086/3585386) answer, using the following code, but did not work (most likely because only two values have labels):

```
labname <- get.label.name(data,"J_Itm1")
labtab <- get.label(data, labname)
table(get.origin.codes(data$J_Itm1, labtab))
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: It's better if you can add a sample of the data, enough to recreate the issue, directly in the post such as with `dput`. People don't necessarily trust third-party anonymous download sites

Comment: Don't read them in as factors in the first place, play with `convert.factors = TRUE, generate.factors = FALSE,` options, read the documentation for `?readstata13::read.dta13` more thoroughly.

Comment: I thought however voted as dupe would at least provide a suggestion of why it might be a dupe. Feels like low effort reviewing to me.

Comment: @jay.sf `convert.factors = FALSE` did the trick. Don't quite understand which was the problem with Stata factors. It seems read.dta13 orders them differently when no all levels are defined.

Comment: @luchonacho Great you found a solution! However, I can't reproduce your issue, actually I see no difference between factor and numeric: `lapply(transform(readstata13::read.dta13('~/Downloads/test.dta'), J_Itm1_num=as.numeric(J_Itm1)), table)` using readstata13 ‘0.10.0’ on R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)).

Comment: I agree that the proposed duplicate target does not seem to fully address the issue. I was unable to find a better duplicate, so I voted to reopen. It would be great if you can self-answer this question. For future reference, [you can @-notify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) any gold badge holder who has bindingly voted to close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is that the package `readstata13` recreates factor values in R, without keeping the order of those in Stata.

The "solution" was to not import levels from Stata. This can be achieved using the `convert.factors = FALSE` option. Although not an optimal solution, it works for me because I do not need factor levels in the first place. I raised an issue in the [package's website](https://github.com/sjewo/readstata13/issues/79) to see potential solutions.